# Nativescript - view tap event pass-thru in iOS?

Tags: nativescript

I've got a Label (#1) and on top of it (and wider and transparent background) I have another label (#2).

I've got a tap event callback set for label #1.

In iOS, it seems like the top label is not passing the tap to the bottom Label - even though there's no tap event set for Label #2.

I set label2.isUserInteractionEnabled to false but no help.

On Android, the pass-thru works fine.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Setting label2.isUserInteractionEnabled to false on the top Label element works as advertised.